# debug messages (logging) showing in the ipython notebook

Tags: python, logging, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have the problem that some debug messages from an my python library are showing in my ipython notebook and cluttering the cell. However, the same messages do not appear if I run the notebook as a script.

I also tried to explicitly set the logging level to INFO but it did not help.

Did anybody had the same problem or could hint me to how to debut this?

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this. I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8282). The quick and dirty solution that I went with was to set the logger's `propagate` attribute to `False`.